# increasing z-index parameter of tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery tooltip and I want to increase its z-index 
I have tried this but it does not work

```
<style>
.tooltip {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: a few tips: make sure they use that specificity (google CSS specificity), put your CSS after the components CSS, and be sure you close the style tag or just put your styles at the end of the last CSS file you are linking in your head, w/o the style tag.

Comment: Are `.tooltip` positioned? `z-index` only applies to positioned elements.

Comment: try `position: fixed`

Comment: I have recheck it and the problem is not with the z-index 
it is cut within the a div

Answer (score 6):

The class you're looking to style is `.ui-tooltip`, not `.tooltip`.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-tooltip {
    z-index: 10000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I checked it out and the default z-index for .ui-tooltip is 9999, so if you want to increase it, it'll have to be higher than that.

Comment: Also, obviously make sure that your css is loaded after the default jquery UI css. If that's not feasible, make it `z-index: 10000 !important;`.

Comment: I alredy fixed it but the real problem now is that it is beeing cutted within a div

Answer (score 0):

The default tooltip has `ui-tooltip` class not `tooltip`.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I got is to add an attribute,where you write data-title,data-placement etc.
You simply have to write

```
data-container="body"
```

This will show the tooltip always on top of everything and this is the standard practice.